# How to navigate between google.script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have created a dashboard with navigation using JavaScript.

However, I am unable to toggle between different HTML created through google.script

Mentioned below is my HTML tags:

```
              <div class="collapsible-body">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="https//:script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby16LFvQvDlEh-pUhHoq36QxwHRxIjshVvg3Pd3EOw7Of6Bu4ic/exec?v=dash" class="waves-effect active">Dashboard<i class="material-icons">web</i></a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="bold waves-effect"><a class="collapsible-header">Leave Management<i class="material-icons chevron">chevron_left</i></a>
              <div class="collapsible-body">
                <ul>
```

currently I receive the following error page: `script.google.com refused to connect.`

How can we achieve to do navigate correctly in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What does your `doGet()` function looks like?

For a WebApp with multiple html pages, you can navigate by retrieving the final part of the URL as an `e.parameter` in `doGet()`.

Sample:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e.parameter.v) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  }
  else{
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['v']).evaluate();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's correct I have made changes in do get and in html `<li><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=dash" `, which does the job thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is the authorization.
I don't know what you put for permission, but check this 
[GoogleAppScripts](https://joshuatz.com/posts/2019/google-apps-script-authorization-in-a-cross-origin-iframe/)

[GithubGoogleAppScripts](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)